# How to upload multiple images at once in react Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to upload multiple images at once, I using Multer as a middleware, I am able successfully upload single image.

Client

```
  const {register,handleSubmit}=useForm() 
    const onSubmit = (images) => {
       let formData = new FormData()
       axios.post(`${url}/uploadMultiple`,formdata)
        }
```

using react-hook-form

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <input type='file' multiple {...register('multipleImages')} />
     <button type='submit' >Upload multiple images</button>
</form>        
    )
```

route

```
route.post('/uploadMultiple',upload.array('imagess'),(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.files)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .array(selector,fileLimit) of Multer. Selector refers to name attribute in your input. fileLimit is used in case you want to limit the number of files

For example:

```
<input type='file' name='images' multiple />
```

```
route.post('/uploadImages',upload.array('images', 10),(req,res)=>{
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simplest way to send images to server

```
  const onSubmit = async(e) => {
        const fd = new FormData();
            [...e.file].map(file => {
                fd.append('imagess',file)
            })

           await axios.post(`${url}/uploadMultiple`,fd)
    }
```

```
import multer from 'multer'

let upload
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req, file, cb)=> {
      cb(null, 'images')
    },
    filename:  (req, file, cb)=> {
      cb(null, Date.now()+ '_' +file.originalname)
    }
  })
  
  export default  upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

node server

```
route.post('/uploadMultiple',upload.array('imagess'),(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.files)
}
```